# Defining methods and field of an Array in a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I would like to be able to build a class where I have an array of integers. I have just made a simple code, but it's not printing the elements of the array. 
The code compiles, but I don't have any results.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int len = 5;

class TrialArray {
    protected:
        int len;
        int A[];
    public:
        TrialArray() {
            for (int i=0; i<this->len; i=i+1) {
                this->A[i] = i;
            }
        }
        void print() {
            for (int i=0; i<this->len; i=i+1) {
                std::cout << this->A[i] << '\t';
            }
        }
};

int main() {
    TrialArray A;
    A.print();

    return 0;
}
```

It's a simple code. in the main, I have the method, `A.print()` and it should print the values, 0,1,2,3,4 in this case but it's not. And I am not understanding where I might be doing wrong.

Comment: `A` is never initialized... Nor is `len`

Comment: *The code compiles,* -- `int A[];` -- This is not valid C++.

Comment: why int A[], is not valid in C++? Shoud I have used int A*?

Comment: It is valid in C99, (flexible array members), tends to bleed into C++ dialects.  Yes, using `int* A` makes it a lot more obvious that you need to allocate the array with new[].  And that you need to google "c++ rule of three".

Comment: I tend to see the int A[] as an array, a container, while int A*, I see it as a pointer. That's why sometimes I overlap these two things, even if those are the same thing. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: *why int A[], is not valid in C++?* -- It isn't valid because the language rules say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the `this->len` variable in the constructor instead of the global static `len`.

Also you have not specified the size of the array.

You need to change your code to properly reference the global variable. A better way to do this is to provide the size of the TrialArray in the constructor.

Change the `int A[]` to `int *A` and dynamically allocate it with `new`.
Store the size given to the constructor in `this->len`, and then populate the array as you have done.

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TrialArray
{
    protected:
        int len;
        int *A;
    public:
        TrialArray(int size)
        {
            A = new int[size];
            this->len = size;
            for (int i=0; i<this->len; i=i+1)
            {
                this->A[i] = i;
            }
        }
        void print() {
            for (int i=0; i<this->len; i=i+1)
            {

                std::cout << this->A[i] << '\t';
            }
        }
};

int main()
{
    TrialArray A(5);
    A.print();

    return 0;
}
```